# How to stop Windows 10 from syncing keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, sync, windows-10, keyboard-layout

I have two laptops, each with its own keyboard layout (AZERTY and QWERTY). Both laptops run Windows 10 and are authorized to sync settings back to my Microsoft account.

The problem is that my keyboard layout setting keeps changing back and forth between AZERTY and QWERTY, for both laptops.

How do I disable that behavior without disabling synchronization altogether?

Comment: I guess you have to turn off syncing for either "Ease of Acess" or "Other Windows Settings" (I don't know which one). Try them in turn to see which one it is. There is no setting for just Keyboard Layout. See [How to Turn On or Off Sync Your Settings in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) for more information (includes which settings can be individually turned on/off)

Comment: If I disable syncing "Language preferences", does that stop it from synchronizing keyboard layouts?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a better one to try. I don't have Windows 10 so I can't test it.

Comment: I assume that also disables syncing other language-settings like date and time format, so this may not be at all what I want.

Comment: I would assume so as well. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a smaller granularity for the sync settings. Perhaps you can write a script which restores the keyboard setting after a sync?

Comment: Note also disabling the scheduled task Microsoft\Windows\International\Synchronize Language Settings may be an alternative as even after that option is off, it appears that some sync still happens from a local cache. (https://github.com/keymanapp/keyman/issues/4447 has some background research on that)

Answer (score 19):

In each of your laptops with Windows 10, go to **Settings -> Accounts -> Sync your Settings**. Then, under *Individual sync Settings*, set **Language Preferences** to **Off**

Comment: This also turns off sync for other language settings like date and time format. Not what I want.

Comment: Still better than having the layouts bouncing. I doubt Windows will allow for finer grained control :(

Comment: My only hope was into the registry, but apparently even that is not finer grained: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I am finding that even if you have a single machine out there with sync turned on - you're gonna have your language settings sync, whether you like it or not. Worse, after some updates, the sync gets switched back to "On".

Comment: Thank you soo much! I was dying between having to change layouts every time between my mac(running windows) and my desktop!

Comment: @frozenjim So you mean turning off sync on one computer only stops uploading settings, but not downloading settings from other computers?

Comment: I turned it off, but it still keeps switching back to the wrong keyboard layout. Any ideas?

Comment: @iBug I am not certain how this intermittent change to sync settings happens.  It happens most often after a forced upgrade.  It appears as you suggest: any synch PUSH overrides the rule for no-sync PULL.